# Chua's circuit's equilibrium at \$x=y=z=0\$

Tags: circuit-design, autonomous

The Chua's circuit satisfies the differential equations from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chua%27s_circuit).

[image]

Clearly, \$x=y=z=0\$ is a solution, but not the solution we see when double scroll appears. Since at \$t=0\$ when we switch on the circuit, \$x,y,z\$ must be all very close to \$0\$, for double scroll to appear, the system must be able to walk away from \$0\$. Therefore, \$0\$ must be an **unstable** equilibrium if the experiment is successful.

However, whether \$0\$ is an unstable equilibrium or not depends on the parameters. So does it mean that, if the parameters are incorrectly chosen so that \$0\$ is a stable equilibrium, then no double scroll can be observed?

Comment: Double scroll?  Define it

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of [one posted on physics.se](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/491310/chuas-circuit-is-x-y-z-0-a-stable-squilibrium). Please don't cross-post on different SE sites. If you've decided that EE is a better site for this question, you can ask the Physics mods to migrate your question over here.

Comment: @laptop2d See the picture on wikipedia.